# Use regex to remove all special characters from string using thymeleaf

Tags: regex, thymeleaf, special-characters

I am new to thymeleaf and recently I partially figured it out how to remove special characters from a string. Following code is working but I have to replace every single special character.

```
${#strings.toLowerCase(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(name, '''','-'), '&',''),' ','-'))}
```

Is there any way around so that I can use a single regex expression to remove all special characters from a string using thymeleaf?

Comment: In your example, which characters are called 'special characters'? (just  '''','-' or all?)

Comment: And what with digits?

Comment: All special characters along with digits. For example,  we can use '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/' expression to remove all special characters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use some code like this:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9]");
strings.replace(name, "", regex1.match(name));
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I am trying to make changes in following HTML snippet :

<div class="auctions-info-wrap"
th:object="${auction}"
th:with="auctionDetailLink=${wbParams != null AND wbParams['wb_auctiondetailsbaseurl'] != null ? wbParams['wb_auctiondetailsbaseurl'] : '/auction-detail/'}
+ |*{#strings.toLowerCase(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(name, '/','-'), '&',''),' ','-'))}/*{guid}/|">

Answer (score 5):

Java `String`s already have a method to replace w/regex:  `string.replaceAll('...', '...')`.  In your case, You can simply do:

```
${#strings.toLowerCase(name.replaceAll('[^A-Za-z0-9\-]', ''))}
```